# Centering multiple images that have their own DIV

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a bunch of images horizontally that each have their own DIV tag. I tried to use text align center but that did not work. Other questions suggested using margin auto for the right and the left sides, but that also did not work. I got it to work with one image, but when i begin to add multiple images the align from top to bottom, I need them aligned horizontally.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;

}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
 }

.container:hover .overlay {
 opacity: 0.5;
}

  .text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">text1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">text2</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
   <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">text3</div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="container">
   <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
   <div class="overlay">
     <div class="text">text4</div>
   </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Share your html as well

Comment: Sorry for the weak code,  but the HTML is there, I only have the picture at the moment.

Comment: Your question itself is not clear like image has it's div tag ?? So it's really hard to know what you want what you're doing

Comment: Basically I want the images aligned horizontally, as if right now it’s vertical

Comment: Dosent matter, as long as the next row is also centered